# does devtool::install_github have a lib argument to control where to save a package

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to install rsconnect using `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rsconnect')`.

The problem is that it appears to attempting to store the package in this directory:

`U:\Documents\R\R-3.6.2` when I want it to go here:`U:\Documents\R\win-library\3.6`

this is a work machine and it's a bit of a mess getting admin privileges.

install.packages() has a 'lib' argument that let's me set the location, but how can I do that with install_github?

Comment: you can use the `lib` argument, and otyhers found in install.packages

Comment: It's odd because I keep seeing devtools::install_github attempting to go to the wrong directory.  

part of the problem is that I've got UNC paths that I think I'm able to navigate around but Here is an example error:

`\\S-N-NSCHOME\nschomes\U999\Documents\R\R-3.6.2 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. `

so, you can see it's use of unc paths, and it's going to the wrong directory.

Comment: its probably worth showing exactly the code you are trying to use; probably a transcription error but the paths should have either double backslash (`\\\`) or forward slash separaltors (`/`)

Comment: I think I'm bumping up what is referenced here:

https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-Install-a-package-from-source-in-Windows-td4683338.html

>Actually, that particular message appears because your *current
working directory* (getwd()) is a UNC path.  So, you must make sure to
call install.packages() with a "regular" working directory.  However,
even if you still do this, I believe install.packages() will give
another error related to the UNC path. 

I may be bumping up against our system admin. :/
.libpaths keep attempting the unc style despite specifying a lib path